# Installing CM 11 (KitKat) on an S II without USB

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb-mass-storage

I've inherited a Galaxy S II running Android 4.1 (no software updates are available for the stock version), and I want to put 4.4 on it. There are plenty of tutorials for this on the internet, but most of them seem to rely on flashing CWM with ODIN first.

My problem here is that USB Mass Storage doesn't work on this phone, and hasn't for about a year now. It will charge over USB, but doesn't appear to acknowledge being connected to a PC. It shows up in Device Manager as *Unknown device*, and in Properties it says *Code 43: Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems*. If I go into settings on the phone and try to switch on USB Mass Storage, it tells me to *Connect a cable before using USB Mass Storage* (or similar wording). I've tried with USB Debugging on and off.

I can, of course, copy files on and off of the SD card using an external reader, what I want to know is whether it is possible to go from stock android (and stock recovery) to CyanogenMod 11 without using the USB connection? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You don't need the USB connection to do this. You need to flash a rooted kernel like Philz which is specific to the S2, and you need to do this from the stock Android recovery which you can access by holding power+home. The rooted kernel must be on the SD card.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm having trouble finding the right versions of CWM and CM to work together - could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you're on stock now, then it doesn't matter what versions you flash at this point, even if they're outdated, you can just update them with newer versions. I would start out with flashing Philz kernel/recovery first, then flashing CM11 (you can always go to CM12 when it's 'done').

Comment: If you still need help with this, add a comment here otherwise if you're  happy  then you could accept the answer.